# Router page and online IP showing page show different IP

Tags: wireless, networking, ip

I have came across an strange situation. Whenever i look at the router page then it
shows an IP which is completely different from the IP i see in the webpages like [ipmango](http://ipmango.com) and other sites too. Can a single computer have two different IP address?

.[image: the image show the different ips]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a computer can have two different IPs given it has two interfaces.

The IP that [ipmango](http://ipmango.com) is showing is known as the Public IP address whereas the IP address the router page is showing is known as the Private IP address.

In a nutshell, you can think of a Private IP address as the address any network other than your Local network will NOT unerstand whereas Public IP address will be understood by those networks. We normally use Private IPs in LAN.
Here are the ranges of Private IPs:

```
Class A: 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255
Class B: 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255
class C: 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255
```

A router is responsible for routing traffics between two or more different networks. So, let just think it this way, your Router has a WAN interface where you will put the Public IP address without which you will not be  able to go to to the internet. The router also has lets say one LAN interface where you will put a private IP so that you local network can be built under this private IP.

For example your router's Public IP is `49.244.254.104` and your router's Private IP is `192.168.1.1`. Now you can have a LAN e.g. `192.168.1.0/24` where all your local computers are allocated private IP addresses between `192.168.1.2` to `192.168.1.254`. All your LAN's traffic will be first reach the Local facing interface (`gateway`) having IP `192.168.1.1` of the router, the router will then route the traffic to the internet by using the Public IP.

Comment: shouldn't the router page show me the public ip and the ip assigned by the router to my computer is 192.168.1.100

Comment: The answer is basically correct. However, it looks like ISP is not dynamically assigning a public IP to its client, but using a Class A IP address to NAT to the public IP 49.244.254.104. This IP is probably shared by many customers of the ISP.

Comment: Think of 49.244.254.104 as your ISP's IP address. 10.17.12.206 is the IP address assigned to your router by your ISP. 192.168.1.100 is the IP address assigned by your router to your computer.